# use UUID for SessionToken when using Google Place SDK for Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

In my Android project I am using Google Place SDK findAutocompletePredictions and fetchPlace methods to get address predictions and then place details.

As per [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#session_tokens) a session token should be used to group the findAutocompletePredictions requests and the final call to fetchPlace together for billing purpose.

As per [dev documentation examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions) a sessionId can be created by calling

```
AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()
```

Reading the official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20version-,4,-UUID%20is%20recommended) I understand that it should possible to use a uuid v4 for session token, however I cannot find any way to generate the AutocompleteSessionToken from a uuid string and a uuid cannot be used directly when calling findAutocompletePredictions/fetchPlace (type mismatch).

How can I generate the AutocompleteSessionToken from a uuid v4?